# How to send contact form using php

Tags: php

Once I submit the form it will aks me this "We weren't able to send your message. Please contact site@sitenamexample.com It will not send to my WebMail. I can't figureout the problem. I really need your help guys.

```
$domain = "http://sitenamexample.com" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
$siteName ="My Website name";
$siteEmail = "site@sitenamexample.com";
$er = "";

if(isset($_POST["contactEmail"])){
 global $subject, $message;

$contactName = htmlentities(substr($_POST["contactName"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
$contactEmail = htmlentities(substr($_POST["contactEmail"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
$messageSubject = htmlentities(substr($_POST["messageSubject"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);
$messageContent = htmlentities(substr($_POST["messageContent"], 0, 100), ENT_QUOTES);


if (!preg_match('/' . '^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})+$' . '/' 
 , $contactEmail))
    {
       $er .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br>';
    }

if ($contactName == "" || $contactEmail == "" || $messageSubject == "" || 
    $messageContent == ""){
       $er .= 'Your Name, E-mail, Message Subject, and Message Content cannot be left    
        blank.<br />';
     }

if($er == ''){

$subject = $messageSubject;
$message = 
'<html>
<head>
     <title>' . $siteName . ': A Contact Message </title>
 .<body>
         ' . wordwrap($messageContent, 100) . '
  </body>
 </html>';
}

$to = $siteName . ' Contact Form <' . $siteEmail . '>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=is0-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $contactName . ' <' . $contactEmail . '>' ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $contactName . ' <' . $contactEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $contactName . ' <' . $contactEmail . '>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: ' . $siteName . "\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
echo '<div>Thank you for contacting ' . $siteName . '. We will read your message and 
      contact you if necessary.</div>';
}

else {
$er .= 'We weren\'t able to send your message. Please contact ' . $siteEmail . 
       '.<br />';
}

}
else {
showContactForm();
}

if ($er != '' && isset($_POST["contactEmail"])){
   showContactForm($contactName, $contactEmail, $messageSubject, $messageContent, $er);
}

else if($er != '' && !isset($_POST["contactEmail"])){
showContactForm('', '', '', $er);
}

function showContactForm($contactName = "", $contactEmail = "", $messageSubject = "", 
                         $messageContent = "", $er = ''){
echo '<div style="font-weight:bold; margin: 5px 0; "> ' . $er . '</div>

<div id="email_form">
<h1> Contact Form</h1>
<form method="post" name="contact" action="#contactus">

<label for="name">Name:</label> 
<input type="text" id="author" name="contactName" class="input_field" />
<div class="cleaner h10"></div>

<label for="email" class="adjust">Email:</label> 
<input type="text" id="email" name="contactEmail" class="input_field" />
<div class="cleaner h10"></div>

<label for="messageSubject" class="adjust">Subject:</label> 
<input type="text" id="messageSubject" name="messageSubject" class="input_field" />
<div class="cleaner h10"></div>

<label for="text" class="adjust">Comments:</label> 
<textarea id="text" name="messageContent" rows="0" cols="0"></textarea>
<div class="cleaner h10"></div>

<input type="submit" class="submit_btn float_l" name="submitButton" id="submit" 
  value="Send Message" />
<input type="reset" class="submit_btn float_r" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>   
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>';
}
?>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php include ("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: $to should only be the emailaddress without any < or >

Comment: @Lithilion on php.net/mail for "to" as example stands (User <user@example.com>)

Comment: Is all this running on windows? What OS is your server running on?

Answer (score 0):

You're code is generally correct (but remember - `$to` should only be the email address without any `<` or `>`). I think the reason of your problem is disabled Sendmail PHP Library - you can enable it in server settings or if you have not access to it - read about [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: check this http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php then see parameters, then check TO: and take a look at some examples of what you can put there

Comment: @Constantin both forms are correct, but this is better because is shorter

Comment: have you read his answer ? `(but remember - $to should only be the email address without any < or >)` and i commented to his answer that there is no limit in using <> or not.